# Int cannot be dereferenced Java

Tags: java, string, int

```
    try
    {
        if (expr.contains("+"))
        {
            return (Integer.parseInt(left) + Integer.parseInt(right)).toString();;
        }
        else if (expr.contains("*"))
        {
            return (Integer.valueOf(left) * Integer.valueOf(right)).toString();
        }
        else if (expr.contains("-"))
        {
            return (Integer.parseInt(left) - Integer.parseInt(right)).toString();
        }
        else
        {
            return (Integer.parseInt(left) / Integer.parseInt(right)).toString();
        }
    }
    catch (java.lang.Exception e)
    {
    }
```

Am trying to do operations on integers,then, convert int to string but am getting int cannot be dereferenced error.

Comment: Which line exactly is giving you this error? What are `expr`, `left` and `right`? Strings?

Comment: @Lutz Yes, All strings

Comment: Never write an empty `catch` block.  At the very least, put `e.printStackTrace();` in it.  The last thing you want is code that fails while quietly pretending it is working.

Comment: @VGR Roger that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt(left) - Integer.parseInt(right)` is an `int`. An `int` is a primitive, so it has no methods, therefore you can't call `toString()` on an `int` value.

You can use the `static` `Integer.toString()` method instead.

For example:

```
return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(left) - Integer.parseInt(right));
```

Comment: return String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(left) - Integer.parseInt(right));